# Mean Field Games: Limiting Measure and Arzela-Ascoli

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory

I am teaching myself Mean Field Games from Carmona's book. "Probabilistic Theory of Mean Field Games with Applications". I want to understand the meaning of this lemma on page 7 of the book.

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ , let $u^n : E^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, be a symmetric function of its variables. Let us further assume that we have,

1. Uniform boundedness: $\sup_{n \ge 1} sup_{\{X \in E^n\}} |u^n(X)| < \infty$.
2. Uniform Lipschitz continuity: there exists a finite constant $c > 0$ such that for all $n \ge 1$ and all $X,Y \in E^n$, we have:
   $
       |u^n(X) - u^n(Y)| \le c \rho ( \overline{\mu}^n_X, \overline{\mu}^n_Y).
      $

Then there exists a sub-sequence $\{u^{n_k}\}_{k\ge 1}$ and a Lipschitz continuous map $U: \mathit{P}(E) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that:
$
   \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{X \in E^{n_k}} |u^{n_k} - U(\overline{\mu}_X^{n_k})| = 0.
  $

My questions are as follows:

1. The condition of uniform boundedness is $\sup_{n \ge 1} sup_{\{X \in E^n\}} |u^n(X)| < \infty$. Here what does the first supremum imply? That it is a supremum over all $n$ which is the dimension of the space $E^n$?
2. Does the conditions $<\infty$ mean that there is a single $M$ such that $\sup_{n \ge 1} sup_{\{X \in E^n\}} |u^n(X)| < M$? Which is what the typical uniformly bounded condition states.
3. The subsequence, this seems to compare two maps a. $u^n: E^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ against $U: \mathit{P}(E) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, such that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{X \in E^{n_k}} |u^{n_k} - U(\overline{\mu}_X^{n_k})| = 0.$ It seems like the dimension of the space is changing, he has $X \in E^{n_k}$?

I am a bit lost at understanding this lemma and what it is trying to say.

Thank you in advance for your answers.